# Feature Request: Answer a question later

Tags: feature-request, questions, profile-page

I've skipped many questions that I can answer because of lack of time. And later, I can't find those questions.

It would be helpful if there were an **Answer Later** feature as an option. Inside my profile would be a section with those questions visible only for me.

Comment: In the meantime, you can click on the star under the question's score, and it will appear under the "favorites" tab, in your profile.

Comment: Actually I'm using "favorites" tab for those questions that I don't know the answer, and I want to know. However, It's a good trick.